Question about the index of two elliptic operators over a 4-dimensional Riemannian manifold
Let $X$ be a compact Riemannian 4-manifold, $P$ a principal $G$-bundle over $X$, and $\mathfrak{g}$ be its adjoint bundle. Let $\omega$ be a self-dual conneciton on $P$ (i.e. its curvature $\Omega \in \Omega^2(\mathfrak{g})$ is self-dual). It induces a covariant derivative $d^\omega:\Omega^0(\mathfrak{g})\to \Omega^1(\mathfrak{g})$, which extends to $d^\omega:\Omega^k(\mathfrak{g})\to \Omega^{k+1}(\mathfrak{g})$ (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connection_(vector_bundle)#Exterior_covariant_derivative_and_vector-valued_forms). Since $\omega$ is self-dual, the sequence $$ 0\to \Omega^0(\mathfrak{g})\xrightarrow{d^\omega} \Omega^1(\mathfrak{g})\xrightarrow{d^\omega_-}\Omega^2_-(\mathfrak{g})\to 0$$
is a complex, where $d^\omega_-$ is the composition $\Omega^1(\mathfrak{g})\xrightarrow{d^\omega}\Omega^2(\mathfrak{g})\xrightarrow{\text{proj.}_-}\Omega^2_-(\mathfrak{g})$ and $\Omega^2_-(\mathfrak{g})$ is the space of anti-self-dual $\mathfrak{g}$-valued 2-forms.
This complex is elliptic, and considering the adjoint $d^*:\Omega^1(\mathfrak{g})\to\Omega^0(\mathfrak{g})$ (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hodge_star_operator#Codifferential) of $d^\omega$, the index of the complex is equal to the index of the elliptic operator $$ d^* \oplus d^\omega :\Omega^1(\mathfrak{g})\to \Omega^0(\mathfrak{g}) \oplus \Omega^2_-(\mathfrak{g})$$
Now my question is the following: Why does this operator has the same index as the Dirac operator $$D:\Gamma(V_+\otimes V_-\otimes \mathfrak{g})\to \Gamma(V_-\otimes V_-\otimes \mathfrak{g})?$$
This is asserted in top of p.445 of Atiyah's paper https://www.math.miami.edu/~cscaduto/teaching/782-fall-2023/notes/AHS.pdf, and it is written that: these two elliptic operators have the same symbol and factor through the same connection. But I can't understand what this mean and that why it implies that two have the same index. (Here, $V_\pm$ are the bundles of self-dual/anti-self-dual spinors, defined in p.428 of the paper.)

I haven't been immersed deeply enough in this topic for a long time to answer this, and I think you'd have a better chance if you asked this on mathoverflow instead.
